# ILP constraint on sum of k variables out n

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, integer-programming

Say I have $n$ variables, denoted $v_n$ and I want to constrain them in the following way
$\sum_{j=1}^{j=k}v_j\le1$ $\forall$ groups of $v$ with cardinality $k$. Obviously there are $n \choose k$ groups, which would lead to a naive implementations with $n \choose k$ constraints. This does not scale and I was wondering if there is a better way of encoding this in ILP or SAT formulation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single constraint $$\sum_{j=1}^n v_j \le 1$$ suffices.  If more than one $v_j=1$, you would have a $k$-subset that violates one of your required constraints.

Comment: I don't think this is sufficient. Plus there is no mention of k in the constraint. Maybe I should rephrase, I want the sum of every subset (of size k) of variables, $v_n$ to be $\le$ 1, otherwise there is no constraint on what $v_n$ need to be.

Comment: I understand. The constraint I proposed is satisfied if and only if your $\binom{n}{k}$ constraints are satisfied.

Comment: Ah I see. thanks.